# Why is octaoxygen diamagnetic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals, magnetism, allotropes

I tried considering that according to LCAO-MO theory $\ce{O2}$ is paramagnetic, which is confirmed by experimental evidence. Since octaoxygen has the crystal structure in figure, I thought there is a kind of overlapping of the molecular orbitals $\pi^{\ast}$  of each $\ce{O2}$ with the others so that the unpaired electrons of one molecule pair with the unpaired electrons of the adjacent molecule, one by one.

I realise this is only an intuitive answer, but I am not much acquainted with quantum mechanics and applied group theory.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This picture of O8 isn't a crystal structure, more of a lame picture of a thing that defies such depiction. The thing is that it *is* an actual O8 molecule, not some loose tetramer. But no, I don't know how it is possible.

Comment: I think what I really mean is sufficiently clear. Anyway, thanks for the invaluable help, I would never have imagined.

Comment: I think one would need to use something like cluster MO theorey here.

Comment: Each oxygen seems to have the standard O$_2$ double bond ($3-1$, actually), plus two other single bonds, so oxygens are in a 10-electron exception to the octet rule, like PCl$_5$. As such, $d$-orbitals must be considered, perhaps in a $\pi^*$ mix (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jX3iAy0xf4) for a similar $sp^3d$ mix).

Comment: But you would need to perform the actual orbital calculations (say using a DFT program) to know how these hybrid orbitals order in energy, so you can aufbau these eight electrons on them. Perhaps a paper worth publishing.

Comment: @Arc Regarding your first comment, oxygen cannot expand the valence shell since it belongs to the second period.

Comment: Oh, yes, I guess you are correct... $d$ orbitals are too far away in energy. Perhaps then there are 2 electrons in each of the two $\pi^*$ molecular orbitals of O$_2$, and only those get mixed. These $\pi^*$ mixed orbitals are strongly bent into the monoclinic structure due to high pressure, but these intra-cluster bond lengths are pretty long as well (almost the double of the O$_2$ bond length).

Comment: I've asked a related question [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8727/how-to-calculate-molecular-orbitals-of-octaoxygen-under-high-pressure).